# Does Amazon DynamoDB support streaming of query results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am investigating the use of Amazon DynamoDB and would like to stream query results to my remote clients.

I cannot find any Amazon DynamoDB documentation that shows it supports said streams.

All I can find are Amazon DynamoDB stream endpoints for live streams as data is changed within the database.

These are not the streams Iam interested in.

I wish to query the Amazon DynamoDB and retrieve the results as a stream to enable me to transmit the streamed data to my remote clients via HTTP.

Does Amazon DynamoDB support this type of streaming of results?

I am looking to deploy code that resembles this on my server

```
private StreamingOutput getStreams() {
        return new StreamingOutput() {

            @Override
            public void write(final OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                outputStream.write(getArticles());
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }
        };
    }
```

and my client uses Retrofit

```
@Streaming
    @GET
    Call<ResponseBody> fetchData();
```

Comment: Results from DynamoDB are typically small, and where that isn't true, they are still paginated into small responses <= 1MB each.  I may be missing something, but it's not clear what the value is of "streaming" results to a client would be, as contrasted with simply re-serializing and "writing" the results to a remote client as a response.  Perhaps you can elaborate.  You may also want to mention your language, assuming you're using an SDK.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot additional details have been added to my question

Comment: Hi @Hector did you find solve for this ? I am also looking for similar use case.

Answer (score -1):

Unless I misunderstood what you're trying to do, DynamoDB does allow streaming. From [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html):

> DynamoDB Streams captures a time-ordered sequence of item-level modifications in any DynamoDB table, and stores this information in a log for up to 24 hours. Applications can access this log and view the data items as they appeared before and after they were modified, in near real time.
>   ...
>   To read and process a stream, your application will need to connect to a DynamoDB Streams endpoint and issue API requests.

[Amazon DynamoDB Streams actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Operations_Amazon_DynamoDB_Streams.html)

Comment: they are not the streams I am referring to. I wish to be able to query the DynamoDB for any data held and return the results as a stream.

Comment: Hi @Hector did you find solve for this ? I am also looking for similar use case.